# Spring Batch unifying multiple reader result

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I would like to unify (merge) an item based on 2 differents sources to read (flat file and DB).
How I can perform that using Spring Batch ItemReader ?

```
public class User {
    Long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String subscriptionCode;
}   

...
stepBuilderFactory.get("createUserStep1")
    .<User, User>chunk(1000)
    .reader(flatFileReader) // Read line from file and create partial user object (only get id, subscriptionCode)
    // Here - How to read DB using User.id read previously and extend User object with additionnal data
    .processor(new SkipDuplicatedUserItemProcessor()) // processor skip duplicated user
    .writer(itemWriter) // Write somewhere
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem should be solved using a reader and a processor.
Use a `FlatFileItemReader` to read your incomplete object and a `ItemProcessor<YourObject,YourObject>` to complete your object with missing informations.

Comment: Ok. But I need another reader to get missing informations. Do I need to perform that in item processor (call JdbcCursorItemReader) ?

Comment: Don't use a reader but perform a direct query (with a service or dao component) from processor

Comment: It's weird to "read" something in a "processor" but if his the only solution... I was looking to make a composite ItemReader that read both flat file and Db sequentially (delegates) and merge bean results (into the reader not the processor). In this case, I can use ItemReader capability (skip policy, ...). What is the best solution ?

Comment: imho the best solution in to perform read into processor.it's not weird; look at 'driving query' pattern (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html)